# Why are there hyperlinks when you scroll up a bunch

Tags: bug, design

On Safari 8.0.6, scrolling up above the ubuntu bar causes links to show up. Is this a bug?

[image: Bug?]

**EDIT**

By scroll up I mean scroll beyond the top limit which is only possible (I think) with the trackpad. For example, if I let go of my fingers when taking this screenshot it would have showed normally.

Comment: It is a bug of Safari.

Comment: The "problem" with theming web sites, IMO, has long been the lack of standards on the browser side. I can write code all day long that is compliant with html5 or what not, but each browser will render the same standard code different. With simple web pages you will not see it as much, but as your themes and sites become more complicated you will. See https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots . No one is going to write code that looks the same across 300 + browsers.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - its not the quantity of browsers that is always the problem i.e. IE :)   **TheWobbuffet**, do you have a bar on your page that looks like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/N9hbT.png) (adding a full-page screenshot would help). Also, are you using any browser extensions installed that could affect the rendering?

Comment: @Wilf - LOL which version of IE ? At any rate Wobbuffet is having a problem with Safari, not IE. IMO they all have issues, if I write code for IE, FF will break and on. I write my web code to 2 web (server) standards https://validator.w3.org/ . From there you optimize as many browsers as possible, starting with the most common browsers hitting your site (assuming you can trust the user agent data).